# babel 6 - options is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm very new to node. I just setup express and babel, and am currently working on [Hello World](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) in express. My first line in `app.js` is the require statement for babel:

`require("babel-core").transform("code", options);`

which yields the error:

`ReferenceError: options is not defined`

in my `.babelrc`, I have this:

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
  "stage": 1,
  "whitelist": [
    "es6.arrowFunctions",
    "es6.blockScoping",
    "es6.classes",
    "es6.destructuring",
    "es6.properties.computed",
    "es6.properties.shorthand",
    "es6.spread",
    "es6.modules",
    "es6.templateLiterals",
    "es7.trailingFunctionCommas",
    "es7.objectRestSpread",
    "es7.asyncFunctions",
    "es7.classProperties",
    "regenerator",
    "flow",
    "react",
    "react.displayName"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": false
}
```

I've been setting up babel according to the [docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-package-json). I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I searched and could not find any info on this issue.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `options` ? if it's a var, you can't use it in the first line of an app, before it's declared. if you don't need it, or don't think you need it, try replacing `options` with `{}`

Comment: Check out the docs for the options input, http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/

Comment: wow, sorry about that. i was treating `options` like a variable that was somehow declared somewhere else, i didn't realize it was a placeholder.  Thanks, both comments helped solve my issue